# Group according to its parent ID

Tags: java

This is the output of my List. I need help in grouping the children with their parent. Note that NodeID is the id of the object and parentID is the id of its parent link to specific NodeID. Thanks for your help.

Code:

```
List<Element> element = new ArrayList<Element>();

for(int i=0; i<element.size(); i++)
{

String nodeName = element.get(i).getName();
String nodeId = element.get(i).getNodeID();
String parentID = element.get(i).getParentID();

System.out.println("nodeID "+ nodeId + "|");
System.out.println("nodeName "+ nodeName + "|");
System.out.println("parentID "+ parentID);
System.out.println("********************************************"); 


}
```

Output:

```
0).
nodeID id_0 |
nodeName Test 3 |
parentID id_0
********************************************
1).
nodeID id_72864 |
nodeName Element A |
parentID id_0 
********************************************
2).
nodeID id_72865 |
nodeName Element B |
parentID id_0
********************************************
3).
nodeID id_72866 |
nodeName Element C |
parentID id_0
********************************************
4).
nodeID id_72867 |
nodeName Element D |
parentID id_0
********************************************
5).
nodeID id_72868 |
nodeName Element E |
parentID id_0
********************************************
6).
nodeID id_72869 |
nodeName Element 1 |
parentID id_72864
********************************************
7).
nodeID id_72870 |
nodeName Element 2 |
parentID id_72865
********************************************
8).
nodeID id_108185 |
nodeName Element |
parentID id_72865
********************************************
9).
nodeID id_72871 |
nodeName Element 3 |
parentID id_72866
********************************************
10).
nodeID id_72872 |
nodeName Element 4 |
parentID id_72867
********************************************
11).
nodeID id_73527 |
nodeName Element 5 |
parentID id_72868
*********************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

*If the list consists of string 'nodeID id_0 | nodeName Test 3 | parentID id_0' as data please split it into a string array first form each '|' character occurence now you will have an array of 3 elements from which you need to find all the unique parent nodes first and the store it in an array parent_unique then compare the all the parent nodes again with the initial split list that consist all values including duplicate parent nodes and eventually fetch all the child nodes data and store it into a different multi dimensional array. If you understand the logic i have provide try to implement in code and you can post the code again i could help you edit(incase it dosen't work out for you).
*

Comment: '|' is just a separation in the println of my code. Element is the object consists of node id, node name and parent id. Can you help me group them according to their parent id? thanks

Comment: Please elaborate as I don't understand what data you have in your list if it an array of list or consits of string elements if possible note below sample code or data with initialization

Answer (score -1):

*Please try executing the below solution and let me know if there is any error or bugs you get. Make sure you give data into this*

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Element> element = new ArrayList<Element>();

    for(int i=0; i<element.size(); i++)
    {

        String nodeName = element.get(i).getName();
        String nodeId = element.get(i).getNodeID();
        String parentID = element.get(i).getParentID();

        System.out.println("nodeID "+ nodeId + "|");
        System.out.println("nodeName "+ nodeName + "|");
        System.out.println("parentID "+ parentID);
        System.out.println("********************************************"); 
    }
    HashSet<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<String>(element);
    for(int i<0;i<uniqueValues.size();i++){
        System.out.println("The below nodes belong to parent node ID :" + uniqueValues.get(i));
        for(int j<0;j<element.size();j++){
            if(element.get(j).getParentID() == uniqueValues.get(i).toString()){
                System.out.println("nodeID "+ nodeId + "|");
                System.out.println("nodeName "+ nodeName + "|");
                System.out.println("parentID "+ parentID);
                System.out.println("********************************************");
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "values" ?

Comment: HashSet<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<String>(values);

what is values?

Comment: Please before rating the post analyze it atleast. values here is your element.get(i).getParentId() and I gave you a business logic how to come over your problem. Please rate the answer positive if you find solution with it

Comment: This are wrong:

-HashSet<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<String>(element);
Error: The constructor HashSet<String>(List<Element>) is undefined

-uniqueValues.get(i)
Error: The method get(int) is undefined for the type HashSet<String>